# Require valid string in Joi which must be in other propertie's array

Tags: javascript, joi

I have the following problem I want to solve with a Joi schema:

There is the property `locales` (arra) and the property `default_locale` (string), the latter must be in the `locales` array.

How can I accomplish this? So far I have the following:

```
Joi.object().keys({
    locales:
        Joi.array()
        .items(
            Joi.string()
            .valid(AllLocales)) // must be any of available locales
        .required(),
    default_locale: // this should be any of the values from locales
        Joi.string()
        .required()
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out I can simply use a `ref` (https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v14.3.1/API.md#refkey-options).

```
default_locale: Joi.string().valid(Joi.ref('locales')).required()
```